# In Grep, how do I add a digit immediately after a backreference?

Tags: grep

If I have a search: `(\d\d):(\d\d)` and I want to add an extra 0 to the numbers that I find (ie, 12:30 would become 120:130), how do I prevent the 0 being interpreted as \10 and \20:

```
\10:\20
```

I tried escaping it with \ but that just made more backreferences. Is there another way to escape in grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original post, you didn't mention that you're using these backreferences in the replacement pattern, not the search pattern. You also didn't mention that you're using BBEdit. Solving your problem requires both of those facts.

From page 209 of [the BBEdit manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/BBSW-download/BBEdit_14.5_User_Manual.pdf):

> \*NNN*+
>
> If more than two decimal digits follow the backslash, only the first two are considered part of the backreference. Thus, “\111” would be interpreted as the 11th backreference, followed by a literal “1”. You may use a leading zero; for example, if in your replacement pattern you want the first backreference followed by a literal “1”, you can use “\011”. (If you use “\11”, you will get the 11th backreference, even if it is empty.)

Therefore you should try this replacement pattern:

```
\010:\020
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, Hmmm, it didn't seem to do anything, just resulted in 12[0]:13[0]. I am using BBEdit's Find & Replace feature to do this so I wonder if the replace input in BBEdit can do character classes as replace isn't pattern searching? I went online to try and see if I could experiment with grep Find/Replace but can't find anything that let me share a link (was looking for something like jsfiddle). Might just have to do a two step process.

Comment: Legend Rob, thanks so much for finding that. Am a little annoyed I didn't think of looking in the BBEdit manual - was so busy googling purely as a grep question and didn't think the answer would be BBEdit specific.